# Query to list all OUTs of department

Tags: sql

DATABASE

| DT_eff | ID | DEPT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 100 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2 | 100 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 200 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2 | 200 |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 | 100 |
| 2023-01-06 | 2 | 100 |
| 2023-01-07 | 1 | 200 |
| 2023-01-08 | 2 | 200 |

`ID` represents a physical *item* that moves between departments. Each row is a point in time record of which `DEPT` that item is in at a given day (`DT_eff`)

we can see in this list that `ID=1` was at `DEPT=100` on the 1st, and on the 3rd it was in `DEPT=200`. We can deduce that on the 3rd, `ID=1` was an output from `DEPT=100`.

I want to output all Effective_Dates (`DT_eff`) where an `ID` came out of the a specific department. This will tell me what items have been processed by that department over time.

In this case, my department is `DEPT=100`. As explained above, I know the `ID` exited the department on day three because its location before that was in my department and it then went to department 200.

OUTPUT

| DT_eff | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2 |
| 2023-01-07 | 1 |
| 2023-01-08 | 2 |

Comment: This is a gap and island issue, but `Day X` is not a good way to store the date value, in the example we really need to use actual values and datatypes so that we can give you an actual answer, not a hypothetical one.

Comment: In the actual data base, it does use real dates (YYYY-MM-DD-h:m:s)

Comment: The sequence is very specific to solving this, is there only ever 1 output for each day? Also is this a real world problem or are you just learning?

Comment: Please use _actual_ data types, dates and strings sort differently Day 10 for instance will normally sort before Day 2 is we just use string sorting

Comment: it usually comes out of the department after 3 days. I missed to specify that the id is unique there are no 2 apples. Trying to learn but it is from a real world exemple we were discussing at work.

Comment: You've made this too generic, and in doing so you miss key learning expriences, so the final solution might be more complicated than if you had used your real structures. For instance this will generate all sorts of discussions about data types, indexes, normalisation that will distract you. Also what RDBMS? each DB has different tools and syntax that can help us here.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that we need to filter the list to return only the rows that the previous `DEPT` value for the same `ID` is equal to `100`.

To do that, we need to define how to find the concept of *previous*, in this case it is the row that appeared before it, we haven't explicitly defined if the `DT_eff` value is unique enough, so to use the ordinal position we can use a `ROW_NUMBER()` window query to generate a sequential index for us. In this example I have used `DEPT` as a secondary sequence, but that wouldn't normally be practical in the real world.

> If there is only ever 1 output per-day, then we don't need row number at all and can use `DT_eff` directly. `ROW_NUMBER ()` is used here in place of the table having an arbitrary sequential key, which is a standard SQL convention.

This example uses [CTEs (`WITH`)](https://learnsql.com/blog/cte-with-examples/), [Window Functions (`ROW_NUMBER()`)](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/) and Sub Queries,
https://dbfiddle.uk/FsHv1W3b

```
WITH Sorted as 
(
    -- Identify the rows and the sort sequence
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (Order BY DT_eff, DEPT) as RECID
         , DT_eff, ID, DEPT
    FROM Production
),
Linked as 
(
    SELECT 
          (-- Previous record in the sequence with the same ID
           SELECT MAX(lookup.RECID) 
           FROM Sorted lookup 
           WHERE lookup.ID = Sorted.ID 
             AND lookup.RECID < Sorted.RECID
          ) as Previous_RECID
        , *
    FROM Sorted 
)
SELECT Linked.DT_eff, Linked.ID, Linked.DEPT
FROM Linked 
-- Join back to the record with the previous RECID, to access the DEPT value
INNER JOIN Sorted Previous ON Linked.Previous_RECID = Previous.RECID
WHERE Previous_RECID IS NOT NULL
  AND Previous.DEPT = 100
```

This query can be optimised from a performance point of view but I find this structure highlights the key logical aspects.

The first optimisation would be to use a [`LAG()` function](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-lag/) with a partition by the `ID` using the `RECID` sequence. If there is a unique sequence column, then we can skip the `Sorted` step altogether, the working is in this fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/Iq3lGGZr

```
WITH Linked as 
(
    SELECT LAG(DT_eff, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DT_eff) Previous_DT
         , *
    FROM Production 
)
SELECT Linked.DT_eff, Linked.ID, Linked.DEPT
FROM Linked 
INNER JOIN Production Previous ON Linked.Previous_DT = Previous.DT_eff
WHERE Previous_DT IS NOT NULL
  AND Previous.DEPT = 100
ORDER BY DT_eff
```

Hopefully that helps understand the different elements and exposes you to a few techniques to achieve the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the database so I'll assume you use PostgreSQL. You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*, lag(dept) over(partition by id order by dt_eff) as pd from t
) x
where dept <> 100 and pd = 100
order by dt_eff;
```

Result:

```
 dt_eff      id  dept  pd  
 ----------- --- ----- --- 
 2023-01-03  1   200   100 
 2023-01-04  2   200   100 
 2023-01-07  1   200   100 
 2023-01-08  2   200   100
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GpOZTR54).